# How to create node.js module proper to VS Code intellisense

Tags: node.js, module, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I coded all js classes according to ES6 and added all JSDoc comments using with eslint. 
I created index.js file for the module which exports necessary classes of node module. 
After linking(npm link) the module and import the classes from other node application I can't see the class files.

Would you write if there is a proper way to create, export modules and import them in order to see every types, properties etc in VS Code intellisense?

Should I generate .d.ts file and import it somehow in VS Code to see them in intellisense?